# Micrometer tracing: Why spanId is a part of traceId and 32 characters long instead of 16?

Tags: java, spring, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

AFAIK, `spanId` and `traceId` which goes into MDC are 16 character Strings. But in my application, I noticed the `spanId` is part of the 32 character traceId. Below is a sample of the same.

> 2023-10-31, [[[traceId=6540ee3f2997f144f45483631005208e, spanId=f45483631005208e]]] [http-nio-8085-exec-1] INFO  com.example.trace.Controller - Inside Hi

I am using micrometer-tracing v1.1.6 with Brave v5.15.1 as my vendor. Following is my `application.properties`

```
server.port=8085
spring.application.name=exampleApp

logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd }, [[[%mdc]]] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

management.tracing.sampling.probability=0.0
management.tracing.propagation.type=B3_MULTI

logging.level.root=info
```

I tried looking into things in debugging mode and found the method that generates it:

```
static String toTraceIdString(long traceIdHigh, long traceId) {
    if (traceIdHigh != 0) {
      char[] result = RecyclableBuffers.parseBuffer();
      writeHexLong(result, 0, traceIdHigh);
      writeHexLong(result, 16, traceId);
      return new String(result, 0, 32);
   }
    return toLowerHex(traceId);
}
```

However this didn't help me much.

How do I get this to add 16 character `traceId` into MDC instead of 32 character traceId+spanId as `traceId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because, in `BraveAutoConfiguration` the `Tracing` object is built with `.traceId128Bit(true)`.

To override this, we will have to define custom `Tracing` bean within our application instead of relying on Spring auto config.

Following is the bean(Taken from `BraveAutoConfiguration` class and tweaked as necessary):

```
package com.example.trace;


import brave.Tracing;
import brave.TracingCustomizer;
import brave.handler.SpanHandler;
import brave.propagation.CurrentTraceContext;
import brave.propagation.Propagation;
import brave.sampler.Sampler;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.tracing.TracingProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(TracingProperties.class)
public class BraveAutoConf {


    @Bean
    public Tracing braveTracing(Environment environment, TracingProperties properties, List<SpanHandler> spanHandlers,
                                List<TracingCustomizer> tracingCustomizers, CurrentTraceContext currentTraceContext,
                                Propagation.Factory propagationFactory, Sampler sampler) {


        //NOTE: skipped the type/produce/consume=W3C and span joining property compatibility check. (This is invalid config)

        String applicationName = environment.getProperty("spring.application.name", "AppName");
        Tracing.Builder builder = Tracing.newBuilder()
                .currentTraceContext(currentTraceContext)
                .traceId128Bit(false)
                .supportsJoin(properties.getBrave().isSpanJoiningSupported())
                .propagationFactory(propagationFactory)
                .sampler(sampler)
                .localServiceName(applicationName);
        spanHandlers.forEach(builder::addSpanHandler);
        for (TracingCustomizer tracingCustomizer : tracingCustomizers) {
            tracingCustomizer.customize(builder);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

This will generate 16 character `traceId` instead of 32 character trace+spanId. However, do note that the traceId and the first spanId will be the same with this configuration.